# Javascript toISOString() different format

Tags: javascript, date

According to Mozilla and I quote

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

I always see YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ format when I invoke method like

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

So in which case

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

will return format like

```
YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ ?
```

Can anyone please give it with example?

Comment: If the year is greater than 4 digits long? `new Date(202021, 0, 1).toISOString()`

Comment: @HereticMonkey surely, we'd have solved the problem by then :P

Comment: It's used for representing BC/ AD

Answer (score 0):

It's the expanded year representation, the extra characters are because it starts with either a `+` or `-` to indicate AD/ BC.

Source: [ISO_8601](https://web.archive.org/web/20171020085148/https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/ISO_DIS%208601-2.pdf)
Section 4.5.1 (on Page 13). A summarized version is [available on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years).

Answer (score -1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years

> ISO 8601 prescribes, as a minimum, a four-digit year [YYYY] to avoid the year 2000 problem. It therefore represents years from 0000 to 9999, year 0000 being equal to 1 BC and all others AD. However, years before 1583 are not automatically allowed by the standard. Instead "values in the range [0000] through [1582] shall only be used by mutual agreement of the partners in information interchange."
>
> To represent years before 0000 or after 9999, the standard also permits the expansion of the year representation but only by prior agreement between the sender and the receiver. An expanded year representation [±YYYYY] must have an agreed-upon number of extra year digits beyond the four-digit minimum, and it must be prefixed with a + or − sign instead of the more common AD/BC (or CE/BCE) notation; by convention 1 BC is labelled +0000, 2 BC is labeled −0001, and so on.